# scrollTo gets overridden when using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, scroll, load, scrolltop

I am creating a mobile web app with jQuery Mobile and would like to hide the search bar above the visible area. So the user would need to pull the page down to see the search bar. I'm thinking the best way to do that is to define the search bar as usual then on page load manually set the scroll position, say down 55px. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("html,body").scrollTop(55);
}
```

The problem is, I can see upon refreshing the page it is hidden from view, but once it has fully loaded it immediately jumps back to the top. jQuery Mobile is the culprit, as it doesn't occur with this simple [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jwRk/1/).

How can I stop JQM from overriding my set scrollTop, or do I need to implement it differently?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Mobile has a special scroll function [`$.mobile.silentScroll()`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.silentScroll/). It scrolls without animation but at the same time it doesn't trigger `scroll` event.

You also need to wait until page is fully loaded into DOM before calling this function. You can bind it to `pagebeforeshow` or `pageshow`.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#page", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.mobile.silentScroll(100);
    }, 10);
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Y46M3/)**

Comment: This works, thanks. It's not perfect though. This isn't working in mobile Safari. It works in desktop Safari though. Even when using `pagebeforeshow` it shows the search bar for a brief moment and then that code gets initiated and the page jumps down and the scrollbar is visible. How could I code it such that it's not noticeable, so it's at that scroll location and then the page is revealed?

Comment: @Omar But suppose I am at the bottom of the page and I refresh the page . After refreshing according to the script you have written will load the page from 100px so can you please suggest how to make it dynamic .

Comment: @Vikram if you _force refresh_ (f5) then you need to check if the current page is the _home page_ and there's no page in jQM's history. Simply, `$.mobile.navigate.history.stack.length > 1` if true, scroll, otherwise, dont.

Comment: @Omar I tried getting the position of the current scroll like this .  `storePosition.topCoordinate =  $(this).offset().top;`  and then used this to scroll the page but its not working

Comment: try delaying it by `setTimeout` sometimes your code fires before jQM finishes displaying the page.

Comment: @Vikram check previous comment ^^.