# scrollTo event overridden when using jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, scroll

After loading, I want a section of the page to be display on the top, so the page scroll will be in that particular place. without the user see scrolling, I want him see immediately the right place on the page.

I load the JQuery mobile script and this override the document ready and load events.
If **I remove the JQuery mobile Script It works perfect**. But I cant remove It.

I tried:

```
 $(window).load(function() {
    window.scrollTo($("#selector").offset().top, 0);
});
```

As mention in - [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393696/scrollto-gets-overridden-when-using-jquery-mobile) I tried:

```
$(window).load(function() {             
        setTimeout(function() {        $.mobile.silentScroll($("#selector").offset().top); }, 100);
                
            }
        });
```

But It didn't work for me.
only in chrome the scroll is in the right place, but in IE, Firefox It didn't.
If I increase the timer to 1000 the IE work but the user see the top of page and after the scroll go to the right position. and this is not good.

I tried:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", '#selector', function() {
            $.mobile.silentScroll(500);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $.mobile.silentScroll(500);
            }, 100);
        });
```

And it didn't work too.

What Do I need to do to, for scroll the page to the right place in all the browsers, Immediately after page had been loaded.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote sample code in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b75oyz3y/), it works in Chrome and Firefox

Here is code that I used:

```
$($("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 500}, 1000));
```

Hope this help

**EDIT**: if you want scroll to be in particular place immediately after page had been loaded then use this code (see [plunker sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/TK6alOjcHJTS6qe9a855?p=preview))

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $("html,body").scrollTop(400);
});
```

Comment: But I don't want the user see the scrolling. I want him to see immediate the particulate section in page.

Comment: Thanks, But it doesn't help. I edited my question and mark that the JQuery mobile override the $(document).ready event. the page scroll to the right position, but after jump again to the top. If I remove the JQuery mobile script all is perfect. It doesn't jump again to the top.

Comment: I needed to do the same, scrolling after page is shown. But somehow it always scrolls to the top. My current fix is to put it inside `setTimeout` with your own interval. Then it should scroll properly. I'm using this.  `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout( 
      function() {
       jQuery('html,body').scrollTop(jQuery('#_id55').offset().top-110);
      }
      , 500);
  });`